# panel analysis for smart meters using plm

Tags: r, time-series

I have panel data for smart meter consumption from around 1000 London households. The households were told ahead of time when the electricity tariff would be low, medium or high. My data looks like this:

```
> head(tof_clean)
             DateTime        id       acorn consumption_Kwh temp_max Tariff tariff_numeric
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000146   Adversity           0.155     7.49 Normal              0
2 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000147 Comfortable           0.276     7.49 Normal              0
3 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000158 Comfortable           0.152     7.49 Normal              0
4 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000165    Affluent           0.401     7.49 Normal              0
5 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000170 Comfortable           0.640     7.49 Normal              0
6 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000173    Affluent           0.072     7.49 Normal              0
```

I want to test to see if there is significance between consumption and times when the tariff is low, medium or high (i have created a numeric variable of 0,1,2 or correspond to the Tariff variable). Since consumption is highly correlated with seasonality I can't simply compare the means of the consumption values so I was hoping to run a panel regression using the plm package.

I have run this code:

```
plm_random <- plm(formula = consumption_Kwh ~ tariff_numeric, data = tof_clean, model="random",index = c("DateTime"))
```

But receive this error:

```
Error in plm.fit(data, model = models[1], effect = effect) : empty model
```

Could you advise on what I am doing wrong and how I can effectively achieve the outcome I am looking for? I am new to panel regression.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using an external package? Do the data you share give the same issue?

Comment: I am using plm package, and the data I have shared gives the same issue. I may be approaching the problem the wrong way though